# How to read specific email in python

Tags: python-3.x, email, imaplib

I have the following code:

```
import imaplib
import email





imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.naver.com')
id = 'abc@naver.com'
pw = '123'
imap.login(id, pw)


imap.select('inbox')
status, data = imap.uid('search', None, '(HEADER FROM "abd@gmail.com")')

if status == 'OK':
    if data[0]:
        mid = data[0].split()[0]
        print('mail id', mid)
        print(imap.fetch(mid, '(UID BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (HEADER FROM)])'))
```

It raised 
`FETCH command error: BAD [b'Error in IMAP command FETCH: Invalid messageset']`

`print (status, data)`

It returned

`OK [b'3769 3838 3845 3896 3907 3916 3961 3978 3989 3991 3993 4002 4017 4059 4069 4607 4608 4612 4613']`

what is wrong in my code?

How can I read specific email?

Comment: What does print('mail id', mid) print?
Also, you are searching for UIDs, but fetching message sequence numbers.  Use imap.uid('fetch', ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a matter of encoding. Try converting it from bytes to string:

`mid = mid.decode('ASCII')`

For the full data set, try:

`msgnums = data[0].decode('ASCII').replace(' ',',')`

Hope this helps! :)